# Expression of $\exp^{-1}\left(z\right)\subset\mathbb{C}$ given $z$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, exponential-function

it might be a stupid question, but I'd like some guidance:

Let $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{ 0\right\}$. How can I express $\exp^{-1}\left(z\right)\subset\mathbb{C}$ with $z$?

I tried following the definition, and I'm not sure how to procceed.

Thank you.

Comment: If $y=e^z$, then $z=\log(y)$. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Hint: starting from $z = e^y$, try to write both sides with a "modulus-argument" form.

Comment: @StevenClark The objective here seems to precisely be describing what all the "$\log(z)$" look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition you have that
$$
\exp^{-1}(z):=\{w\in \mathbb{C}: e^w=z\}\tag1
$$
Now observe that $e^{w}=e^{\operatorname{Re}(w)}\cdot e^{i \operatorname{Im}(w)}=z$ if and only if $|z|=e^{\operatorname{Re}(w)}$ and $\operatorname{Im}(w)\in \operatorname{Arg}(z)$, where $\operatorname{Arg}(z)$ is the set of arguments of $z$, that is, all real numbers $\varphi $ such that $z=|z|\cdot e^{i \varphi }$.

Then you can describe (1) also as
$$
\exp^{-1}(z)=\{w\in \mathbb{C}: \operatorname{Re}(w)=\ln |z|\,\land\, \operatorname{Im}(w)\in \operatorname{Arg}(z)\}\tag2
$$
If you set $\arg(z)$ as the principal argument of $z$, i.e., as the unique $\varphi \in \operatorname{Arg}(z)$ such that $\varphi \in(-\pi,\pi]$, then the above can also be written as
$$
\exp^{-1}(z)=\{w\in \mathbb{C}: \operatorname{Re}(w)=\ln |z|\,\land\, \operatorname{Im}(w)\in \{\arg(z)+2\pi m:m\in \mathbb{Z}\}\}\tag3
$$
I think that something like (2) or (3) is the purpose of the exercise.